# creating SSIS package using SSDT 2017

Tags: ssis

I want to use Visual Studio 2017 SSDT to create a SSIS package. However, I can't see any SSIS template in SSDT 2017, as it exists in previous versions of Visual Studio such as VS 2015. Could someone give me some hints on how to do that? Thanks, A

Comment: Can't see it? what exactly are you doing? I press File / New Project then go to the Business Intelligence folder. Do you see a business intelligence folder? What version of SSDT?

Comment: You may need run the installer again and "Modify" and add the SSIS component.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I go to File /New Project, there is nothing about  Business Intelligence. I also tried to modify it only the location of installation and language can be changed.

Comment: Are you sure you are running SSDT and not Visual Studio? Are you sure you installed SSDT and not Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a 2-step process.  You need to ensure that you enabled **Data storage and processing** from your Visual Studio installation AND you need to download and install the SSDT standalone installer.

This page details the instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017

SSDT standalone installer is here: https://download.microsoft.com/download/D/F/8/DF8B51B9-8E9F-47F3-A27B-33EEDADD8966/SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe

Comment: Thank you. I was missing part of the installation as you noticed.